# Faster way to color table cells in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I use VBA to create tables in Word from csv files. Some cells should be colored, so for these values I use a character "&" in original csv:

```
.......
1,234   6,789   &4,321e+05
&-5,55  1,999   0,00
.......
```

Then I use a loop through table cells:

```
    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(ActiveDocument.Tables.Count)
    For Each ce In tbl.Range.Cells
        a = ce.Range.Text
        If InStr(a, "&") Then
            a = Replace(a, "&", "")
            ce.Range.Text = a
            ce.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorGray20
        End If
    Next
```

Since there can be many tables, and tables can be pretty large, this is sometimes very slow. Is there a faster way to do it?

Comment: it is slow because you are reading cells from the document one by one and running some functions to paint and replace their value. Your best bet is to turn all your table data to an array, run your macro and save the address of all cells that will be painted in another array, then loop through that array and paint the cells and remove the special character from there. Loops in arrays are a lot faster than loops through ranges.

Comment: @Ibo Thanks for suggestion, I will try this.

Comment: please let us know the outcome!

Answer (score 0):

This will turn off screen updating, which means you will not visually see the macro run but it will help increase the speed.

```
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Comment: Yes, I use it, but it still takes up to 15 minutes to create a file.